# Scala method notation using def name_= not working?

Tags: scala, oop, methods

whenever I try to run this simple code it says that balance is not a member of Playground.cat

I read about this notation in a book, so I am confused on why it isn’t working?

```
class cat(var _balance:Int) {
    def balance_=(nb:Int) = _balance = nb
}
val c = new cat(5)
c.balance +=25
print(c._balance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet, please:

```
class cat(var _balance: Int) {

  def balance_=(n: Int) = _balance = n

  def balance = _balance
}

val c = new cat(5)
c.balance += 25
print(c.balance)
```

(https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5ZiUDYizQHSJqjR3pYugYA)

If I'm getting it right, scala also needs accessor for `_balance` value with the same name, as `c.balance += 25` gets "expanded" by compiler into 
`c.balance = c.balance + 25`

Comment: I would say, that if there are both setter and getter that don't contain any additional logic, the simplest solution is to get rid of both of them and just define `class cat(var balance: Int)  {}`

Answer (score 2):

> whenever I try to run this simple code it says that balance is not a member of Playground.cat
>
> I read about this notation in a book, so I am confused on why it isn’t working?

The error message spells it out pretty clearly: it cannot find the member `balance`, in other words, you are missing the getter.

It is also spelled out pretty explicitly in [section 6.15 *Assignments* of the Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignments) [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## 6.15 Assignments
>
> ```
> Expr1        ::=  [SimpleExpr ‘.’] id ‘=’ Expr
>               |  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs ‘=’ Expr
> ```
>
> The interpretation of an assignment to a simple variable  `=`  depends on the definition of . If  denotes a mutable variable, then the assignment changes the current value of  to be the result of evaluating the expression . The type of  is expected to conform to the type of . **If  is a parameterless method defined in some template, and the same template contains a setter method `_=` as member**, then the assignment  `=`  is interpreted as the invocation `_=()` of that setter method. Analogously, an assignment `. =`  to a parameterless method  is interpreted as the invocation `._=()`.

To fix it, you need to add a getter of the same name in the same template (that's the name the SLS uses for class, trait, or object):

```scala
class Cat(var _balance: Int) {
    def balance            = _balance
    def balance_=(nb: Int) = _balance = nb
}

val c = new Cat(5)

c.balance += 25

print(c._balance)
```